# How to find network type in java

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

`NetworkInterface` provides a list of available interfaces on a device. How do I find out the type of internet interface(Ethernet / Wifi). For example `ConnectivityManager` in Android allows to check for connection type.

I have tried going through `ifconfig` information to find out the network type, but it doesn't seems to work. Assuming `en0` and `en1` to be ethernet and wifi respectively doesn't seems to be a good idea. In case of mac, even though I am connected through wireless, `en0` is active and has the correct ip address.

Comment: maybe just do the `ipconfig` command and open a stream to it... then read and see which one has your ip/etc

Comment: Ahh didn't see that mac part.. Yeah so just run a `ifconfig` command and do that

Comment: OP addresses the problems of using `ifconfig` in his question. @3kings

Comment: `ifconfig` will obviously show more information if you are connected to wireless doesn't matter if the IP shows up the same. A few simple if statements would do...

Comment: Could you please run `iwconfig` and report the results.

Comment: part of Ifconfig output is below. en0 is the connected interface but I can't really tell if its wireless or ethernet. @3kings.  en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500  
 ether 6c:40:08:ad:a6:ec   
 inet6 fe80::6e40:8ff:fead:a6ec%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4   
 inet 10.19.54.17 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 10.19.55.255  
 nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>  
 media: autoselect  
 status: active

Comment: I am not able to add linebreaks in comments, that's why output looks like this. Sorry about this